# Apollo GraphQL useQuery re-fetching when history.replace method is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, apollo-client, browser-history

I have a page that utilizes the Apollo GraphQL useQuery hook to fetch data from several different sources. Some of that data is displayed on the page in a list, and some gets populated into select menus that the user can change in order to filter data on the page. I'm also using a simple React hook for persisting the users selections via the `history.location.state` object (specifically using React Router Dom). The hook is essentially this:

```
history.replace({
  ...history.location,
  state: {
    ...history.location.state,
    [key]: value,
  },
});
```

The issue I'm running into is that whenever `history.replace` gets called **all** of the queries re-fetch data, even if nothing has changed and it should serve a cached result. I've been struggling to find any information around when and why the Apollo client decides to re-fetch and if there's anything I can do to avoid this – will Apollo by default respond to any changes to the history object and cause a re-fetch?

Comment: This seems unusual indeed. Are you accidentally re-rendering the component that constructs and provides a `new ApolloClient` to your application?

Comment: @Bergi - shouldn't be, I have a global GraphQL provider hook/HOC that wraps essentially the entire application.